# Doubt about Hard Sphere Model

Tags: ideal-gas, molecular-dynamics

I couldn't find a proper answer about this question: if I have a gas formed by a single species (ex: biatomic gas like O2), what is the diameter $\sigma$ of the relative hard sphere model?
Is it the diameter of the molecule or the diameter of the potential influence or something else?